# Extract topological features from dataframe an add them to a new, expanded dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cross-validation

I have this `df` whose features I'd like to train, test and validate, using cross-validation:

```
RangeIndex: 370 entries, 0 to 369
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   round              370 non-null    int64  <---- will be dropped
 1   home_team_goal     370 non-null    int64  <---- will be dropped
 2   away_team_goal     370 non-null    int64  <---- will be dropped
 3   home_best_attack   370 non-null    float64
 4   home_best_defense  370 non-null    float64
 5   home_avg_attack    370 non-null    float64
 6   home_avg_defense   370 non-null    float64
 7   home_std_attack    370 non-null    float64
 8   home_std_defense   370 non-null    float64
 9   gk_home_player_1   370 non-null    float64
 10  away_avg_attack    370 non-null    float64
 11  away_avg_defense   370 non-null    float64
 12  away_std_attack    370 non-null    float64
 13  away_std_defense   370 non-null    float64
 14  away_best_attack   370 non-null    float64
 15  away_best_defense  370 non-null    float64
 16  gk_away_player_1   370 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(14), int64(3)
```

---

> **Dataset**

My dataset, however, must include some added topological features (which captures diagrams and geometrical relationships between the original set of features above).

This is how I need my dataset to end up like, in a `pandas` dataframe:

```
    Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------              --------------  -----  
 0   home_best_attack    2565 non-null   float64
 1   home_best_defense   2565 non-null   float64
 2   home_avg_attack     2565 non-null   float64
 3   home_avg_defense    2565 non-null   float64
 4   home_std_attack     2565 non-null   float64
 5   home_std_defense    2565 non-null   float64
 6   gk_home_player_1    2565 non-null   float64
 7   away_avg_attack     2565 non-null   float64
 8   away_avg_defense    2565 non-null   float64
 9   away_std_attack     2565 non-null   float64
 10  away_std_defense    2565 non-null   float64
 11  away_best_attack    2565 non-null   float64
 12  away_best_defense   2565 non-null   float64
 13  gk_away_player_1    2565 non-null   float64
 14  bottleneck_metric   2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
 15  wasserstein_metric  2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
 16  landscape_metric    2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
 17  betti_metric        2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
 18  heat_metric         2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
 19  label               2565 non-null   float64   <---- will be added
```

---

> **Test Feature Extraction**

I have the following methods for extracting those added features from the original dataframe:

```
def extract_topological_features(diagrams):
    metrics = ['bottleneck', 'wasserstein', 'landscape', 'betti', 'heat']
    new_features = []
    for metric in metrics:
        amplitude = Amplitude(metric=metric)
        new_features.append(amplitude.fit_transform(diagrams))
    new_features = np.concatenate(new_features, axis=1)
    return new_features

def extract_features_for_fantasy_prediction(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, pipeline):
    shift = 10
    top_features = []
    # run as main
    all_x_train = x_train[:, :14]
    all_y_train = y_train
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(x_test), shift)):
        #
        print(range(0, len(x_test), shift))
        if i+shift > len(x_test):
            shift = len(x_test) - i
        batch = np.concatenate([all_x_train, x_test[i: i + shift]])
        batch_y = np.concatenate([all_y_train, y_test[i: i + shift].reshape((-1,))])
        diagrams_batch, _ = pipeline.fit_transform_resample(batch, batch_y)
        new_features_batch = extract_topological_features(diagrams_batch[-shift:])
        top_features.append(new_features_batch)
        all_x_train = np.concatenate([all_x_train, batch[-shift:]])
        all_y_train = np.concatenate([all_y_train, batch_y[-shift:]])

    final_x_test = np.concatenate([x_test, np.concatenate(top_features, axis=0)], axis=1)
    return final_x_test
```

---

> Cross Validation

and this is my code for doing so:

```
def cross_validate(self, full_x, full_y, splitting_dates):
        train_split_date = splitting_dates[0]
        val_split_date = splitting_dates[1]
        end_date = splitting_dates[2]

        train_x = full_x[(full_x['round'] > train_split_date) | (full_x['round'] <= end_date)]
        train_y = full_y[(full_x['round'] > train_split_date) | (full_x['round'] <= end_date)]

        val_x = full_x[(full_x['round'] >= train_split_date) & (full_x['round'] < val_split_date)]
        val_y = full_y[(full_x['round'] >= train_split_date) & (full_x['round'] < val_split_date)]

        test_x = full_x[(full_x['round'] >= val_split_date) & (full_x['round'] < end_date)]
        test_y = full_y[(full_x['round'] >= val_split_date) & (full_x['round'] < end_date)]

        train_x.pop("round")
        val_x.pop("round")
        test_x.pop("round")

        train_x = train_x.values
        train_y = train_y.values
        val_x = val_x.values
        val_y = val_y.values
        test_x = test_x.values
        test_y = test_y.values

        print("START VALIDATING MODEL")
        models_cv = self._validate_k_fold_model(train_x, train_y, val_x, val_y)
        best_model_params = best_combination(models_cv)
        best_model_params.pop("score")
        best_model = RandomForestClassifier(**best_model_params)

        best_model.fit(train_x, train_y)

        score = best_model.score(test_x, test_y)
        print(f'score no_top {score}')
        print(f'best model parameters no_top {best_model_params}')

        print("START VALIDATING PARAMS")
        topo_cv = self._validate_k_fold_top(best_model, train_x, train_y, val_x, val_y)
        best_topo = best_combination(topo_cv)
        best_topo.pop("score")
        best_topo_pipeline_list = [('extract_subspaces', SubSpaceExtraction(**best_topo)),
                                   ('compute_diagrams', VietorisRipsPersistence(n_jobs=-1))]
                                   
        best_topo_pipeline = Pipeline(best_topo_pipeline_list)

        train_x_for_test = np.concatenate([train_x, val_x], axis=0)
        train_y_for_test = np.concatenate([train_y, val_y], axis=0)

        diagrams_train, _ = best_topo_pipeline.fit_transform_resample(train_x_for_test, train_y_for_test)
        print("EXTRACTING TOPOLOGICAL FEATURES TRAIN")
        top_features_train = extract_topological_features(diagrams_train)
        x_train_model = np.concatenate([train_x_for_test, top_features_train], axis=1)
        best_model.fit(x_train_model, train_y_for_test)

        print("EXTRACTING TOPOLOGICAL FEATURES TEST")
        x_test_model = extract_features_for_fantasy_prediction(x_train_model, train_y_for_test,
                                                       test_x, test_y, best_topo_pipeline)
        score_top = best_model.score(x_test_model, test_y)

        val_x_with_topo = extract_features_for_fantasy_prediction(train_x, train_y, val_x, val_y, best_topo_pipeline)

        print('START VALIDATING MODEL WITH OPTIMAL TOPOLOGY')
        model_config_with_topo = self._validate_k_fold_model(x_train_model[:train_x.shape[0]], train_y, val_x_with_topo, val_y)

        best_model_config_with_topo = best_combination(model_config_with_topo)
        best_model_config_with_topo.pop('score')

        best_model_with_topo = RandomForestClassifier(**best_model_config_with_topo)
        best_model_with_topo.fit(x_train_model, train_y_for_test)

        score_best_topo_and_model = best_model_with_topo.score(x_test_model, test_y)
        print(f'score best model and topo_feat {score_best_topo_and_model}')

        return best_model_params, best_topo, best_model_config_with_topo, score, score_top, score_best_topo_and_model
```

---

QUESTION:

Running the following code...

```
y = compute_match_result(df)
df.pop('home_team_goal')
df.pop('away_team_goal')

cv = CrossValidation(k_mins=k_mins, k_maxs=k_maxs, dist_percentages=distances, **model_params)
cv_output = cv.cross_validate(df, y, (train_split_date, val_split_date, end_date))
```

---

...and since most of features are being computed as `arrays`, at precisely which point of `cross_validation()` above (and HOW) can I add the topological features to the original `df`, ending up with the desired dataset (datarame) above?

---

Note: full code can be found [here](https://github.com/giotto-ai/football-tda/blob/master/cross_validation.py).

For a dataset sample:

```
pip install openml
```

Then at the top of the script:

```
from openml.datasets import get_dataset
```

and:

```
x_y_df = get_dataset(42188).get_data(dataset_format='dataframe')[0]
```

Comment: I'd say it would be easier to understand with a sample of your dataset (it's heavy code !).

Comment: the sample is in the link above...in the note.

Comment: Does it not makes sense to do the feature extraction like they do in the notebook here:  https://github.com/giotto-ai/football-tda/blob/master/FootballTDA.ipynb

Comment: @MarkH @Mark H On your link, when dataset is loaded invoking `load_dataset()`, the dataframe is already formatted like the desired result above. all training features (including topological) are already there. what I need is precisely to build that dataset that will THEN be loaded in order to extract the test features. so I need to add the topological on top of the other features, to build the full TRAINING dataset. does this make sense to you?

Comment: Sorry, I thought he was augmenting the dataframe via:  x_test = extract_x_test_features(x_train, y_train, new_players_df_stats, pipeline)

Comment: @MarkH I think this extraction might be happening with `top_features_train = extract_topological_features(diagrams_train)`, in `cross_validation`, but am not sure.

Comment: extract_x_test_features is in notebook_functions.py and calls extract_features_for_prediction in cross_validation.py , which calls extract_topological_features (also in cross_validation.py)

Comment: Yes, I know, all I need to know is how, and at which point, along this chain, to save the dataframe with topological features extracted at disk. Because the project loads it directely from openml repository.